# Display images in table cell using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

i have a table with 1row, 2 column
left column display product brand (eg: apple, samsung, oppo)
when user click on samsung, i would like to display Only all related images of samsung phone model on right hand side.
how to achieve it? i dont have any database installed at this moment, all images physical files are kept in images folder of my application.

Comment: Maybe create a javascript array(s) of files and show the correct ones in html `<img` tags based on an ID after a button click?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need, the best way might be to actually use JavaScript to filter those images.

I createad a simple script for you:

```
function filterImg(className) {
    for(var img of document.querySelectorAll(".filter")) {
        img.style.display = "inline-block";

    if(className.length && !img.classList.contains(className))
        img.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Working example here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t432ebfr/2/)

Comment: hi Saeed, appreciate your reply. what would be the file name of my image? eg: i have 3 apple, 4 oranges? any image objects required in my design interface ?

Comment: Hi Saeed, I replace the code ClassName with my class <fruit_test.aspx> name  from ClassName change to fruit_test but it still cant work.

Comment: Hi Saeed, I replace the code ClassName with my class <fruit_test.aspx> name from ClassName change to fruit_test but it still cant work. Number of fruits can be filtered But unable to display image correctly. I had checked the directoryof image it was valid. Image in itself is clear.

Comment: Sounds like you are mistaking file name for class name. If you are not familiar with CSS selectors I suggest you read a little about them and make sure you look at the jsFiddle example link I provided.

Comment: Hi Saeed, I revert the file name back to using ClassName already but it still unable to display related images.